# Improving Firebase Database Design for Mobile Application

Tags: swift, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, database-design

I'm making a forum-style app in iOS app using Firebase, and I'm wondering if there's anything I can do to improve my database structure. I'm worried about the "HOME" part, where each post will require 2 api calls to receive the poster's image URL. If there are 1000 posts, it will be 2000 api calls per refresh per user.

**Login: 1-3 calls**

- CheckUsers: 1-3 firestore calls depending if user exists

  - Get Users
  - Save User / Create User
  - Set Group

**Home: 1 Firestore call + 1 Firestore call/post + 1 Storage call/post (if not cached)**

- retrievePost():

  - Get All Posts : 1 firestore call
  - For Loop

    - Get User Thumbnail: 1 firestore call per post
    - Load Image: 1 storage call per post (image is cached)

**Add Reply: 3 calls**

- Add a Reply collection document to the Post document: 1 firestore call
- Increment “replies” field by 1: 1 firestore call
- Add reply post ID to user DB: 1 firestore call

**Add Post: 1 call**

- Add Post to DB: 1 firestore call

**Like/Unlike Post: 1 call**

- Add/remove from array: 1 firestore call

**Account: 1 Firestore call + 1 Storage call**

- Update User DP:

  - Upload image to storage: 1 storage call
  - Set image URL to User DB: 1 firestore call

Answer (score 0):

You could make a local temporary dictionary which maps the user ID from each post with a profile pic URL. That way if a person posted multiple times it'd only make an API call the first time.

Also, add pagination so that you're not loading 1k posts at a time